# Alias causes error: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: bash, alias

I am trying to run the follow bash and getting the error: `` bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' ``.

.bashrc:

```
alias "ota"='/cygdrive/d/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/esp8266com/esp8266/tools/espota.py'
```

I was trying run the following command:

```
ota --help
```

Comment: You might have to escape the parantheses and spaces in the paths with backslashes: `/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/...`

Comment: Might be easier to just add another set of quotes: `alias 'ota="/cygdrive/d/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/esp8266com/esp8266/tools/espota.py"'`

Answer (score 7):

**tl;dr**

- **You need to quote your alias command not just for its *definition*, but *also* for its *use* *as-is* on the resulting command line.**
- The simplest solution in your case is to use a **combination of outer `'...'` quoting with *inner* `"..."` quoting** (other solutions exist; note that the use of `"..."` for inner quoting means that if your definition contained variable references, they'd expanded when the alias is *used*):

```
alias ota='"/cygdrive/d/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/esp8266com/esp8266/tools/espota.py"'
```

---

There are ***two* quoting (escaping) contexts that come into play** when you define an alias:

- Quoting when you *define* an alias.
- Quoting in the context of the command that an alias is *used* in.

---

The quoting in your alias definition allowed you to *define* alias `ota` without a syntax error:

You defined alias `ota` as the following *literal*:
`/cygdrive/d/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/esp8266com/esp8266/tools/espota.py`
i.e., the *literal* content of the string on the RHS, due to use of `'...'` (single-quoting).

---

However, when you *use* this alias in command `ota --help`, its definition becomes a *literal, unquoted* part of the command line, and Bash tries to execute the following *broken* command:

```
/cygdrive/d/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/esp8266com/esp8266/tools/espota.py --help
```

Based on the usual [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html), this command is processed as follows:

- `/cygdrive/d/Program` is interpreted as the command to execute (everything before the first whitespace), because *word splitting* splits the unquoted tokens on the command line into words by whitespace.
- Therefore, `Files`, `(x86)/Arduino/hardware/esp8266com/esp8266/tools/espota.py` and `--help` become the *arguments* to that command, BUT: `(` and `)`, when used *unquoted*, as they are here, are *control operators* to the shell: they are used to create *subshells*, but doing so as part of an *argument* is *syntactically invalid*, which is why you're seeing `` syntax error near unexpected token `(' ``
  (before a runtime error of not finding command `/cygdrive/d/Program` has a chance to kick in).

The above illustrates the need to make proper quoting an *embedded* part of your alias definition, as illustrated at the top.
Alternative solutions can be found below.

---

#### Quoting alternatives:

```
# Using *outer double quotes with inner double quotes* would work here too,
# although if the definition contained variable references / command or 
# arithmetic substitutions, they'd be expanded at *definition* time.
alias ota="'...'"

# Using an *ANSI C-quoted string ($'...')* inside of which you can use
# \' to escape embedded single quotes (but you need to be aware of
# the meaning of other \-based escape sequences).
alias ota=$'\'...\''

# Using *character-individual quoting*, with \ preceding each shell 
# metacharacter (as in @sorontar's answer).
alias ota='/cygdrive/d/Program Files\ \(x86\)...'
```

#### Using a *function* instead:

@[ruakh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978917/ruakh) points out that using a  *function* instead of an alias bypasses the two-tiered quoting headaches altogether:

```
function ota() { 
 '/cygdrive/d/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/esp8266com/esp8266/tools/espota.py' "$@"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to backslash-escape certain characters in your commands. In particular, you need to escape the spaces in the file names to prevent the shell from splitting the file names into multiple parts. You also need to escape the `(` and `)`, which are meta-characters for the shell:

```
alias "nano"='/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' 
alias "ota"='/cygdrive/d/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Arduino/hardware/esp8266com/esp8266/tools/espota.py'
```