# Why am I intermittently getting "syntax error near unexpected token `('" from my function definition, depending upon the terminal I use?

Tags: bash, git, shell, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-rider

I suspect that I have an issue similar to [Alias causes error: syntax error near unexpected token `('](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697288/alias-causes-error-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token), (exact same error message) yet it differs in that:

1. I am trying to define a function, not an alias.
2. I have other functions defined in *the exact same way* as far as I can tell, that work fine.
3. The error disappears if I use a different terminal emulator ([iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/) to be specific).

The tl;dr section of the linked question's top voted answer states:

> You need to quote your alias command not just for its definition, but also for its use as-is on the resulting command line.
>
> The simplest solution in your case is to use a combination of outer '...' quoting with inner "..." quoting (other solutions exist; note that the use of "..." for inner quoting means that if your definition contained variable references, they'd [be] expanded when the alias is used)

But this makes zero sense to me. Bash is seemingly picking up a <kbd>`</kbd> character where there is none, either in the OP's situation or in mine.

The appropriate section of my `.bash_aliases` file:

```
# Checkout the given branch of mine, without having to type the "users/kent/" prefix
gc() { git checkout users/kent/$1; }

# Create and checkout a new branch in my user folder, without having to type the "users/kent/" prefix
gcb() { git checkout -b users/kent/$1; }

# Rename a local Git branch, without having to type the "users/kent/" prefix
gr() { git branch -m users/kent/$1; }
```

Within the integrated terminal in [JetBrains Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) (a cross-platform .NET IDE), the top two aliases work fine, but the bottom one doesn't...which is extremely confusing to me, especially since **they all work** in iTerm2!

Comment: A partial hint, the error message is purely about `(` being an unexpected token. The backtick is just a single quote that matches up with the one on the right. Some shell programs show "smart" quotes by using backticks for the opening quotes. It's purely a typographical choice, in other words; it's not choking on any backticks in your shell script.

Comment: Naive question: why don't you (double-)quote the `$1` variables in your functions? Other than those functions, do you have custom _aliases_ defined in your `.bashrc`? You could try to backup your current `.bashrc`, remove all "custom" contents and re-add them one by one.

Comment: Thanks @JohnKugelman, good things to know. And @Grobu, I didn't realise double-quoting was so damn important lol...a good practice, I know, but yeah. And these functions are defined in a `.bash_aliases` file, which is *then* included in `.bashrc`. As the name suggests, yes, there are mostly alias definitions in this file. So yeah, I'll try your suggestions and see how I go. Thanks :-)

Comment: Is `gr` somehow already defined as an `alias` when running in JetBrains Rider? An alias would be expanded before the function declaration is evaluated. Perhaps it's being expanded to something like `git branch -m users/kent/$1() { git branch -m users/kent/$1; }`, which is an obvious syntax error.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Hmm interesting...it was at one stage, so perhaps the issue is Rider keeping some kind of cache of my user files which isn't getting updated. Thanks for hopefully pointing me in the right direction ;-)